# AngularJS $(filter) doesn't receive Date() function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, filter

Having a small malfunction here.

When i receive a date input I can than transform it to whatever format I want (controller wise)
(e.g)

> registerReq.dateFormat = $filter('date')(registerReq.dob, 'dd.MM.yyyy');

Works like a charm.

Now when I try to do the same thing on a Date() function
(e.g)

> var timestamp = Date();
>
> registerReq = $filter('date)(timestamp, 'dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm');

It doesn't work.

I tried looking for information but i'm kinda lost.

Thanks for your answers! Fede.

Comment: I think the single quote in your `registerReq = $filter('date)(timestamp, 'dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm');`. Check the `'date`, missing quote.

Comment: nope . i just wrote it here. it's a typo
>registerReq.dateFormat = $filter('date')(registerReq.dob, 'dd.MM.yyyy');
that's the right one, and still.

Comment: where are you getting `$filter` from?

Comment: inject to a controller

Comment: @FedeSc Did you try `new Date()` instead of `Date()`?

Comment: @AlbertoI.N.J. OMG - that was all! please comment your answer so i can vote for it! thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `Date()` to `new Date()`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: have to wait three minutes from post. coming right at ya! :)